# Show downloaded files in system Download UI in android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm writing an app which has it's own `download manager` and store files in `System's Download folder`. I just don't want to show the files in Download folder instead I wan't to show it in `System's Download app` like the following image.

Is it possible to show the downloaded file in `Download app` without using `Android's DownloadManager`?

[image]